# wcstok causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, split, substring, c-strings, wchar-t

I'm writing program that splits cyrillic text from stdin and prints it line by line. After reading text using `fgetws` i am getting Segmentation fault. Debugging with `gdb` returns this:

```c
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
wcstok (wcs=0x7fffffffda90 L"", delim=0x7fffffffda80 L" ,-", save_ptr=0x0) at wcstok.c:45
45      wcstok.c: No such file or directory.
```

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>

int main() {
    wchar_t sentence[201];

    fgetws(sentence, 201, stdin);
    
    wchar_t delimiters[] = L" ,-";

    wchar_t *word = wcstok(sentence, delimiters, NULL);

    while (word != NULL) {
        wprintf(L"%ls", word);
        word = wcstok(NULL, delimiters, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am using gcc 9.4.0

Comment: Is it legitimate to pass NULL for the 3rd parameter? The docs say "ptr - pointer to an object of type wchar_t*, which is used by wcstok to store its internal state".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These calls of `wcstok`

```
wchar_t *word = wcstok(sentence, delimiters, NULL);

while (word != NULL) {
    wprintf(L"%ls", word);
    word = wcstok(NULL, delimiters, NULL);
}
```

are incorrect. The third argument shall not be a null pointer.

You should write something like the following

```
wchar_t *ptr;

wchar_t *word = wcstok(sentence, delimiters, &ptr);

while (word != NULL) {
    wprintf(L"%ls", word);
    word = wcstok(NULL, delimiters, &ptr);
}
```

From the C Standard (7.29.4.5.7 The wcstok function):

> 3 The first call in a sequence has a non-null first argument and
> stores an initial value in the object pointed to by ptr. **Subsequent
> calls in the sequence have a null first argument and the object
> pointed to by ptr is required to have the value stored by the previous
> call in the sequence,** which is then updated. The separator wide
> string pointed to by s2 may be different from call to call.